# How to implement chromium openSearch?

Tags: html, xml, chromium, opensearch

I'm trying to implement the Tab To Search on my website URL by using opensearch. I followed the steps in openSearch Documentation but still didn't work for me. please help me in figuring out what I'm missing.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <ShortName>localhost</ShortName>
 <Description>Search localhost</Description>
 <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="localhost:8080/?query={searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

And my Head tag in the index.html file is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="search"
          type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
          title="Google IFL"
          href="tabToSearch.xml">
 </head>
```

Result: Whenever i press the Tab button it jumps to the next url enter image description here
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure is correct, the issue is that you forgot to add an http protocol in template.
Without the protocol, it won't be added to chrome.

```
-  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="localhost:8080/?query={searchTerms}"/>
+  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://localhost:8080/?query={searchTerms}"/>
```

Once you do this, you will be able to see it in Chrome custom search engine settings.
[image]

However, it will work when you try to search `localhost` but not `localhost:8080`. It will still use the good port in search. This is because the search keyword will not have the port.

Comment: hi @abkarino, thanks for replying, actually i tried adding the http protocol the way you suggested, but still not working not even with the localhost keyword. any other hints ?

Comment: Check that the entry is found in the settings. Also I recommend that you try with any local domain and port 80 for test. `http://luna.local`. Just put it in hosts file to point to 127.0.0.1 and I can assure you it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has removed support for opensearch.xml.

> Change #1: We made it so new Site search shortcuts are no longer automatically added to the Chrome search bar. We did this to help avoid cluttering it with Site search suggestions that people may not be using. (2/6)

https://twitter.com/googlechrome/status/1504858912692084745

Edge still supports this feature.